# TerminateAction.java is missing in the Package org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.context for Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

We are trying to update eclipse from my project from 3.2.2 to 3.7.2. and found that `TerminateAction.java` is missing in the package `org/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/actions/context`. Can someone please tell me what could be the alternative for `TerminateAction.java` for 3.7.2. and why it has been changed.

I have found bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293109 related to Terminate and Relaunch but nothing found for TerminateAction.java

I would really appreciate a quick help on this.

***Update:***
Below is the code snippet which is referring the TerminateAction.java:

```
`IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
if (page != null) {
 LaunchView view = (LaunchView) page.findView(IDebugUIConstants.ID_DEBUG_VIEW);
 if (view != null) {
    TerminateAction action = (TerminateAction) view.getAction("terminate");
    if (action != null) {
     action.contextChanged(view.getViewer().getSelection(), view);
        }
    }
}`
```

**@Chandrayya G K :**
Here the contextChanged is the method that belongs to class `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.context.AbstractDebugContextAction` class so I think I can not use `TerminateCommandAction` here because it is extending `DebugCommandAction.java` which is missing that function.

***Where can we find the `contextChanged()` method or can we go ahead and create our own `TerminateAction` class similar to older one.***

Please suggest any alternate solution is there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse classes with `internal` in the package name are for **internal use only** and as such are subject to change or removal without notice - see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

The debug plugin defines a [command](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_commands.html) with id `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate` which sounds like it may be what you want. Try calling that command.

Update:

Basically by using this internal code you have dug yourselves in to a big hole.

`AbstractDebugContextAction` was also internal and has been removed, as has the `contextChanged` method. The `IAsynchronousTerminateAdapter` interface all this terminate code used has also gone. It looks like all this code was refactored to use the newer `command` and `handler` paradigm over the older JFace `Action`.

You should be able to invoke the new `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate` command using `IHandlerService` but you will have to work out what it expects in terms of current selection and the like.

Comment: Greg, Thanks for the quick reply, I have updated my query. May be it will help you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Check in [Eclipse 3.2.2 SDK javadoc](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.2.2-200702121330/) that whether this class is deprecated. I think so.

When searched for this class(`TerminateAction`) in grep code, I found the [results like this](http://grepcode.com/search/?r=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24eclipse.org%243.7.2&start=0&query=TerminateAction&entity=type). Means this class is refractored and rename to some other classes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have updated my query. May be it will help you to understand better